# Cloud Functions FieldValue increment TypeError in Firestore

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am testing cloud functions in the firebase emulator and getting an error when trying to increment a field in the cloud firestore. Please check my code & error message below. Thanks for any help!

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

export const newUserIncrementStat = functions.firestore.document("users/{uid}").onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const docRef = db.doc("stats/users");

  try {
    return docRef.set({
      totalUsers: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
    }, {merge: true});

  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Something is wrong: ", e);
    return Promise.reject(e);
  }
});
```

**Error Message from Firebase Logs:**

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'increment')

**Dependencies**

firebase-admin: "^11.0.0"

firebase-functions: "^3.22.0"

firebase: 11.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @Min commented the error was with the firebase emulator, deploying the function directly to google cloud works without any error.

Answer (score 9):

It`s a issue with modularity improvement of firebase-admin. You can I rolled back to firebase-admin v10.3.0 or use modular import `import { FieldValue } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';`

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import { FieldValue } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

export const newUserIncrementStat = 
functions.firestore.document("users/{uid}").onCreate((snap, context) => 
{
    const docRef = db.doc("stats/users");

    try {
    return docRef.set({
        totalUsers: FieldValue.increment(1),
    }, {merge: true});

    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Something is wrong: ", e);
        return Promise.reject(e);
    }
});
```

Or you can fully convert to modular import:

```
import type { FieldValue, getFirestore } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');


const app = initializeApp();
const db = getFirestore();

export const newUserIncrementStat = 
functions.firestore.document("users/{uid}").onCreate((snap, context) => 
{
    const docRef = db.doc("stats/users");

    try {
    return docRef.set({
        totalUsers: FieldValue.increment(1),
    }, {merge: true});

    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Something is wrong: ", e);
        return Promise.reject(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: THat worked for me , this modularity drives me nuts ...

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're not correctly setting a reference to your document.

Try `const docRef = db.collection("stat").doc("users")`.

Instead of using set and giving it `merge:true` option you can just use update like this:

```
docRef.update({
  totalUsers: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
});
```

This will increment totalUser count by 1 even if there was no field name totalUsers before.

Comment: Hi Min, Thanks for your response. I changed the docRef as you suggested and also changed the set method to the update method, but I still get the same error. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Does it work when you deploy the function? I’m not sure they fixed it but there used to be error when dealing with increment and arrayUnion in emulator

Comment: Hi Min, Thanks for the suggestion, deploying the function works. The emulator seems to be the problem. Thank you!