# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'increment')

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Cloud Functions and I need to increment a counter inside the emulator. Here is what I have tried:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const increment = admin.database.ServerValue.increment(5);
```

But I got the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'increment')

The weird thing is that when I use the same line when I deploy for example a function, it works fine. How to solve this inside the **emulator**?

Comment: The error means that `admin.database.ServerValue` is `undefined`. I'd start by looking at what properties *are* defined on `admin.database`.

Comment: @Pointy The [firebase-admin.database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.database) contains the [ServerValue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.database#servervalue). How can it be `undefined`? Why doesn't work only inside the emulator?

Comment: I have no idea, but it's clear that it is in fact `undefined`. As I said, it might be interesting to see what `admin.database` contains at the point your code gets that error.

Comment: @Pointy Everything I try to call in the emulator that exists inside `admin.database` is `undefined`. Why does it work when I deploy a regular Cloud Function?

Comment: Checkout the answer from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73079648/cloud-functions-fieldvalue-increment-typeerror-in-firestore/73561562#73561562 It fixed it for me

Answer (score -1):

Replace admin.firestore with Firestore

```
const { Firestore } = require("firebase-admin/firestore");
```